# execution sequence of parallel execution plan

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, performance, parallelism, performance-tuning

I am reading an article about [Understanding Parallel Execution](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database-performance/geist-parallel-execution-1-1872400.html)

There is a paragraph which is as follows:

[image: Description]

But for my understanding of how to read an execution plan, this parallel execution plan starts from operation 7 not operation 14.

Why this article emphasize that the execution plan starts at operation 14?? It upside down my knowledge of execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the quoted text Oracle will only have two parallel active per data flow operation. Take a look at the TQ column of the EXPLAIN PLAN. There is only one data flow operation for this query (Q1). There are five different parallel slave sets for Q1:

```
Q1,00
Q1,01
Q1,02
Q1,03
Q1,04
```

`Q1,00` and `Q1,01` will be processed first. The operation on line 7 (FTS on T3) has a slave set of `Q1,02` so it can only start after `Q1,00` or `Q1,01` finish and free up a slave set.

Comment: does parallel execution plan not execute by the execution tree order?

Comment: As far as I can tell that is the point that the author is making: "Second, if you know how to interpret serial execution plans regarding the order of execution, you might be surprised by the fact that the Consumer / Producer model, along with the buffering, can lead to scenarios where the usual rules do not apply."